# How to zoom in the x axis on the geopandas plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

So i want to expand this image, you can see it looks weird on the x axis so Im really new on working with geopandas and all this stuff:[image: 1]

```
    from importlib.resources import path
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pathlib
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np
from os import environ
import shapely.geometry
def suppress_qt_warnings():
    environ["QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO"] = "0"
    environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
    environ["QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS"] = "1"
    environ["QT_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suppress_qt_warnings()

#f = pathlib.Path() / "GEOJSONDESCARGAS" /"mapa_base_Limites_Municipales_IGN_2021.json"
x= gpd.read_file("mapa_base_Limites_Municipales_IGN_2021.json")

x.plot(cmap="jet",edgecolor= "black", column="municipio")
#plt.xlim(100.0, 5500000.0)
#plt.figure(figsize=(1,1),dpi=80)
plt.style.use("seaborn")
#plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Comment: why do you have all those QT settings set? what happens if you don't set them? I expect that setting the scale factor to 1 is your problem

Answer (score 0):

- you have not provided a link to the **geojson** you have used.  Have replaced it with **geojson** that is area limits in Pamplona. Add a link to where the **geojson** can be found to question
- this does plot as expected,  with appropriate scaling of axes with you code
- clearly your **geojson** is a different CRS (this is obvious from scale of values in axes)

```
from importlib.resources import path
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pathlib
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np
from os import environ
import shapely.geometry
def suppress_qt_warnings():
    environ["QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO"] = "0"
    environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
    environ["QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS"] = "1"
    environ["QT_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suppress_qt_warnings()

#f = pathlib.Path() / "GEOJSONDESCARGAS" /"mapa_base_Limites_Municipales_IGN_2021.json"
# x= gpd.read_file("mapa_base_Limites_Municipales_IGN_2021.json")
x = gpd.read_file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/montera34/airbnbnavarra/master/data/output/limites/barrios-pamplona-wgs84.geojson")
x = x.rename(columns={"BARRIO":"municipio"})

x.plot(cmap="jet",edgecolor= "black", column="municipio")
#plt.xlim(100.0, 5500000.0)
#plt.figure(figsize=(1,1),dpi=80)
plt.style.use("seaborn")
#plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```